# ServletPath changes from RESTEasy 3.0.10.Final to 3.0.23.Final

Tags: wildfly, resteasy, wildfly-8

I've upgraded my Wildfly 8.2.1.Final with a new version of RESTEasy to be able to use SNI support (not available in 3.0.10.Final version). So I copied the resteasy-jboss-modules-3.0.23.Final content in my ***/wildfly/modules/system/layers/base*** directory. But now I have a different behavior ! my Rest services are not called. And when I've inspected the context/servlet path I found different values between 3.0.10.Final and 3.0.23.Final versions:

With RESTEasy **3.0.10.Final** I have the following values :

```
        String contextPath = request.getContextPath(); // = "/myApp"
        String servletPath = request.getServletPath(); // = "/api"
        String pathInfo = request.getPathInfo(); // = "/auth"
```

And with RESTEasy **3.0.23.Final** I have :

```
        String contextPath = request.getContextPath(); // = "/myApp"
        String servletPath = request.getServletPath(); // = "/api/auth"
        String pathInfo = request.getPathInfo(); // = null
```

my jboss-web.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web>
    <context-root>/myApp</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

And I have no servlet mappings in my web.xml. All I have is class extending **javax.ws.rs.core.Application** with **@ApplicationPath** annotation :

```
@ApplicationPath("/api")
public class RESTActivator extends Application {
    private final Set<Class<?>> classes;

    public RESTActivator() {
        HashSet<Class<?>> c = new HashSet<>();
        c.add(ARestService.class);
        c.add(AnotherRestService.class);
        classes = Collections.unmodifiableSet(c);
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        return classes;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do the servlet mappings in your web.xml look like?

Comment: @Steve C  I have updated the question with mappings configuration

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour of `request.getServletPath()` and `request.getPathInfo()` in a JAX-RS context is not defined by the specification, so I guess that an implementation is free to manage these how it sees fit.

If these path components are important to you consider using the services of an injected [javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/UriInfo.html) via [@javax.ws.rs.core.Context](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Context.html) instead.

Comment: When I inject a javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo with @Context I get null

Comment: Even when a request is being processed?

Comment: Yes even when a request is being processed